# How can I prevent displaying a file in address bar?

Tags: php

I have a site and I want to create a log.txt file which includes all user logs.For example a user logged in anytime and logged out. That is to say,time which users logged in and out. I can make this with database but there would many rows and I don't want it. If I put log.txt file to /logs/log.txt,any user who writes domain.com/log/log.txt to address bar will see that file. How can I prevent this. (I use PHP)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a database? This is exactly the use case for one; 'too many rows' doesn't make sense since databases were designed for this case.

Comment: Uh, write the log file to a location outside the publicly accessible web root?

Comment: You can't prevent it using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that you can hide files from website visitors using `.htaccess`, or by putting similar rules in other Apache configuration locations. But this kind of thing is not trivial, and it's easy to make mistakes. The best way to hide files from site visitors is through the directory structure of your project. For instance:

- A directory `www/` to contain all files website visitors DO need to visit directly with a browser. This will the the directory used as we website root in your Apache configuration. If browsers don't need to fetch a file, it should not be here.
- Other directories, like `logs/` for logs, `lib/` for source code that gets included in your scripts, `config/` for settings and configuration files, etc. Since they're not inside of the website root (`www/`), users cannot point their browsers at any of these files.

If you're on shared hosting, and they only give you one folder that is your website root, then you can't do this. I wouldn't purchase a hosting account from such a company, though, because there are plenty that DO let you put files outside your web root.

Answer (score 1):

Use a .htaccess with

```
   <Files "log.txt">
        order deny,allow
        deny from all
        allow from 1.2.3.4
    </Files>
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is your IP, if you want to be able to acces it from your browser via the site. Else remove that line, so you will only be able to access via FTP or script

Comment: Not a good idea. if something needs to be inaccessible, then it shouldn't be inside the document root. Apache configs are far to easy to screw up and doing so will expose the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent http access to your log folder by using an .htaccess file that contains

```
deny from all
```

Comment: Better yet, just put anything 'private' outside of the document root, which makes it naturally inaccessible.